# Why do all my field IDs have "--2" as a suffix?

Tags: entities, users

On my registration form, the field IDs used to be `edit-field-first-name`, etc. Now all of a sudden they are `edit-field-first-name--2`.

Every single field has the `--2` suffix.

I updated all my styles to reflect the new IDs, but then I noticed that if I submit the form with an error, the repopulated form now has no such suffix, and all of the styles are broken.

What can i do to get rid of this suffix permanently?

Comment: [`drupal_html_id()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_html_id/7) will be the 'culprit' - is this form AJAX-enabled? That's what usually invokes the new IDs

Comment: @Clive sort of. I have completely overwritten `user-register.tpl.php` and I am calling `print render($form['field_name']);` manually for each field, so that must be creating the 2nd ID. Am I going about that wrong?

Comment: Wrong is such an ugly word - you're going about it in a sub-optimal way :) What you really want to do is alter the form (`hook_form_alter()`) and apply a `$form['#theme']`. That theme item will be one you register yourself through `hook_theme()`, and the theme function/template file will be responsible for theming the form only (not the rest of the page). Trying to pick forms apart and render pieces individually, outside of the 'proper' theming mechanism, never goes that well in my experience.